# Как изменить цвет материала skybox c помощью кода в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу изменять цвет фона, если плеер дошел к финишу. Фон залит в градиент из двух цветов, один нужно изменить, к примеру синий в красной. Как это сделать с помощью кода?

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Tile")
    {
        meters+=1;

            if(meters==20)
            {
                speed=20;
            }
            else if (meters==50)
            {
                speed=25;
            }
            else if (meters==100)
            {
                speed=0;
                panel.SetActive(true);
                final_text.SetActive(true);
                resetBtn.SetActive(true);
                backMenu.SetActive(true);

            /// Ёще здесь нужен код, чтобы менять цвет фона. 

        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Shader]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если быть вкратце, то пишем:

```
RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("YourProperty", YourColor)
```

YourProperty - название твоего свойства в Edit Shader панели скайбокса, цвет которого хочешь изменить, а YourColor - соответственно цвет, который хочешь поставить.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74299/discussion-on-answer-by-fan4i-----skybox-c--).